# How would I use Promises to fix this issue of synchronization in React?

Tags: reactjs, synchronization

I am working on a group project where we have to make a weather app. I am doing the details section, which displays values such as temperature, humidity, chance of rain, etc. from an API. I am using two different APIs in this project as OpenWeatherMap does not have some of the data I need. A different section of our app is getting the location and it is passed down to my section, where it is put into the OpenWeatherMap URL without issue.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    if(this.props.location) {
        this.fetchWeatherData1();
        this.fetchWeatherData2();
    }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(this.props.location != prevProps.location) {
        this.fetchWeatherData1();
        this.fetchWeatherData2();
    }
}

fetchWeatherData1 = () => {
    let urlOWM = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + this.props.location + "&units=metric&APPID=" + API_KEY_OWM;
    $.ajax({
        url: urlOWM,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success : this.parseFirstResponse,
        error : function(req, err){ console.log('API call failed ' + err); }
    })
}

parseFirstResponse = (parsed_json) => {
    var feelsLike = this.formatTemp(parsed_json['main']['feels_like']);
    var humidity = this.formatPercentage(parsed_json['main']['humidity']);
    var wind = this.formatSpeed(parsed_json['wind']['speed']);
    var visib = this.formatVis(parsed_json['visibility']);
    var cloud = this.formatPercentage(parsed_json['clouds']['all']);
    var lat = this.formatString(parsed_json['coord']['lat']);
    var long = this.formatString(parsed_json['coord']['lon']);

    // set states for fields so they could be rendered later on
    this.setState({
        feelsLike: feelsLike,
        humidity: humidity,
        windSpeed: wind,
        visibility: visib,
        cloudCover: cloud,
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: long
    });      
}
```

In parseFirstResponse(), I store the latitude and longitude values for the location. I have to do this because the second API (DarkSky) URL can only take the coordinates for some reason. Here is the code below, where I am placing the state values for latitude and longitude into the URL:

```
fetchWeatherData2 = () => {
    let urlDS = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/" + API_KEY_DS + "/" + this.state.latitude + "," + this.state.longitude + "?exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,alerts,flags";
    $.ajax({
        url: urlDS,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success : this.parseSecondResponse,
        error : function(req, err){ console.log('API call failed ' + err); }
    }) 
}

parseSecondResponse = (parsed_json) => {
    var precipChance = parsed_json['currently']['precipProbability'];
    var precipType = "";

    if (precipChance == 0.0) {
        precipType = "Precipitation";
    }
    else {
        precipType = this.capitalize(parsed_json['currently']['precipType']);
    }

    precipChance = this.formatDecimaltoPercentage(precipChance);
    var uv = parsed_json['currently']['uvIndex'];
    var dew = this.formatTemp(this.fToC(parsed_json['currently']['dewPoint']));

    // set states for fields so they could be rendered later on
    this.setState({
        precipChance: precipChance,
        precipType: precipType,
        uvIndex: uv,
        dewPoint: dew
    });      
}
```

When I run this code and put a location in for the first time, I get an error in the console that says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()" and the URL looks like this: https://api.darksky.net/forecast/767ed401d519be925156b6c885fce737/undefined,undefined?exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,alerts,flags&callback=jQuery34106961395668750288_1585829837010&_=1585829837011
When I put a second, different location in, however, without refreshing the page, the URL and API call works without issue.

The coordinates of the location are supposed to be where the words "undefined, undefined" are. I have tried to console.log() the latitude and longitude values in my parseSecondResponse function and gotten the right values. I think this is a synchronization issue, but I'm not too sure.

Putting the fetchWeatherData() functions in the explicit ordering of 1 then 2 in my componentDidMount() function does not seem to help. I read about using Promises but I am not very familiar with React, so I am unsure how to implement them/if they will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I made small changes:

1. use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API);
2. remove fetchWeatherData2 from componentDidMount;
3. use componentDidUpdate;

```
import React from 'react';

class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { location } = this.props;

    if (location) {
      this.fetchWeatherData1(location);
      //fetchWeatherData2() your cannot call this because latitude and longitude === null
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { location: prevLocation } = prevState;
    const { location: currLocation } = this.props;
    const {
      latitude: prevLatitude,
      longitude: prevLongitude,
    } = prevState;
    const {
      latitude: currLatitude,
      longitude: currLongitude,
    } = this.state;

    if (prevLocation !== currLocation) {
      this.fetchWeatherData1(currLocation);
    }

    if (prevLatitude !== currLatitude || prevLongitude !== currLongitude) {
      this.fetchWeatherData2(currLatitude, currLongitude);
    }
  }

  fetchWeatherData1(location) {
    fetch(http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&units=metric&APPID=${API_KEY_OWM}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        // parse you data here
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          latitude: data.coord.lat,
          longitude: data.coord.long,
        }));
      })
      .catch(({ message }) => {
        console.error(`API call failed: ${message}`);
      });
  }

  fetchWeatherData2(latitude, longitude) {
    fetch(https://api.darksky.net/forecast/${API_KEY_DS}/${latitude},${longitude}?exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,alerts,flags`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        // parse you data here
      })
      .catch(({ message }) => {
        console.error(`API call failed: ${message}`);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble fully testing this code because of an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error I get when trying to access the DarkSky API. I have tried adding the line "mode: no cors" in my fetch statement, but then I get an error "Unexpected end of file". Do you know any way to fix this? I also have somehow exceeded my API calls for OpenWeatherMap; could this have been caused by the code you posted?

Comment: I actually was able to use a proxy server to get around the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error and the code works great! Thanks so much for the help.